# how to decide no. of cores and executor in aws

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

i have a data size of 5 TB and if i decide to use r4.8xlarge EC2 machine which has memory = 244 GB  per machine and CPU = 32

how can i now decide no. of cores and executors i have to use?

i tried few combination of cores and executors but spark job fails with heap space issue, i have listed it below excluding other parameters

```
--master yarn 
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4000 
--driver-memory 25G 
--executor-memory 240G 
--executor-cores 26
--num-executors 13
```

Comment: Maybe you could say more about how many files in your dataset, average size of these files, and your code.

Comment: 6 input sources is fed into the spark job, out of which 2 sources have huge files with files on an average sizing 1 GB, the work here is to ingest data from S3 to postgres, i have the entire script in shell and processing it in EMR.